# Fetching SRV using InitialDirContext failing on Java 14 and below

Tags: java, vpn, java-11, java-15

We are making use of **getAttributes** method on **javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext** for SRV record, this is being attempted from local laptop connected to company VPN through Global Protect 5.2.6-87 version. The below lines of code **works absolutely fine from Oracle Java 15 onwards**, however it **fails on Oracle Java 14 and below** throwing exception highlighted below

> DirectoryNotFoundException: Unable to lookup service directory for
> authority: _srv_record._tcp.ip
> _srv_record._tcp.ip : javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DNS name not found [response code
> 3]

```
InitialDirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(props);
Attributes attrs = ctx.getAttributes("_srv_record._tcp.ip", new String[] {"SRV"});
```

The API documentation for javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext does not have significant difference from [Java 14](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.naming/javax/naming/directory/InitialDirContext.html) to [Java 15](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.naming/javax/naming/directory/InitialDirContext.html). Looking at any inputs to figure out the reason, why the above lines of code **works from Java 15 onwards** and **fails below Java 15** ? Thank You.